# The geometry of a spiral made of adjacent right triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality

[image]

In the above figure (not sure if  you can see it clearly or not), while using the old standard technique of plotting irrational numbers on number line, I saw this property.  If we go on plotting irrationals on top on another (like plotting $\sqrt{3}$ as hypotenuse of $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$) the irrational $\sqrt{17}$ crosses X axis and make an angle of $2.87$ degrees.  I want to prove it algebraically, i.e., to prove that
$$
\tan^{-1}1+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} > 2\pi
$$

Can anybody help me prove this, please, (please comment if you have problem viewing the image) ?

Comment: Image link( if not seen clearly ) http://postimg.org/image/wcicliqql/

Comment: That link doesn't look to function in your answer. Try uploading it from your PC directly using the image tool.

Comment: Plz forgive me, But I dont know how to DIRECTLY ost image , can u tell

Comment: When editing your question, you should see a list of editing options (boldface, italics, etc.) If you click the sixth icon (the blue square) you'll be able to insert an image. Pick the upload from computer option and select it from wherever you've saved it to your PC.

Comment: Glad to help. You could make the image much easier to read by only showing the triangles themselves. (Obviously you use the circles and lines in constructing the figure, but they don't seem helpful for the final image.)

Comment: This is related to the "spiral of Theodorus": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus

Comment: @MichaelLugo - Does that spiral have any relation with an Archimedean spiral?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: [yes!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus#Archimedean_spiral)

Comment: Dinsih: There appears to be an error in your construction of $R$: In your diagram, it's drawn as collinear with $P$ and $Q$ which should not be the case. I think you didn't construct the correct right angle in there.

Comment: Oh Yes, I had made a mistake,, instead of perpendicular to Q, I made it perpendicular to R. Sorry. :(